# You have error syntax VB.Net MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sql-update

I want update mysql database table in vb.net, i try and i got problem with that. this is my source

```
 MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=db4free.net;port=3306;userid=***;password=***;database=***"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "update member set (Name='" & Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox6.Text) & "' WHERE Username='" & TextBox8.Text & "'"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

If i do this source, i got error code like this
[image]

Comment: remove the bracket `(` after set

Comment: done but keep not working :(

Comment: ok, update your answer to remove the bracket and add the exact contents of Query

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox1.Text = 10
TextBox6.Text = 20
TextBox8.Text = John
```

Here's what you have

```
"update member set (Name='" & Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox6.Text) & "' WHERE Username='" & TextBox8.Text & "'"
```

render:

```
update member set (Name='30' WHERE Username='John'
```

-

What you probably want is to remove the bracket

```
"update member set Name='" & Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox6.Text) & "' WHERE Username='" & TextBox8.Text & "'"
```

resulting in :

```
update member set Name='30' WHERE Username='John'
```

My suggestion to you as a preference for building these strings is to separate the parameters more often. It keeps things neat and easy.

ex:

```
dim x as string = (Val(TextBox1.Text) + Val(TextBox6.Text)).tostring
dim cmd as string =
 "update member " &
 "set Name=" & "'" & x & "' " &
 "WHERE Username=" & "'" & TextBox8.Text & "'"
```